# Min/inf and max/sup of $\frac{|1-xy|}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

My assignment is to find the $min$ and $max$ (or $inf$ and $sup$) of the set
$$\mathbb{A} := \left\lbrace \frac{|1-xy|}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}:\ x,y \in \mathbb{R}, x\neq y\right\rbrace$$

I know that $\inf \mathbb{A} = \min \mathbb{A} = 0$ and $\sup \mathbb{A} = 1$. The assignments says there is no explanation required. I found these by "guessing" However, I want to know how to find these two values in a mathematical way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, using $2xy \le x^2 + y^2$, 
$$|1-xy| \le 1+|xy| \le  1+ \frac{x^2}{2} +\frac{y^2}{2} \le 1+x^2 +y^2\le (1+x^2)(1+y^2),$$
so the function value is less than one. The above equality holds only when $x = y=0$, so the function value is strictly less then one (as $x\neq y$ by requirement). On the other hand, let $y = 0$, it becomes 
$$\frac{1 + 0}{(1+x^2)(1+0)} = \frac{1}{1+x^2}.$$
Let $x\to 0$, one see that the supremum (not maximum) is one.

The minimum is easier: it's obviously non-negative and by finding some $x,y$ so that $xy=1$, the minimumu (thus also the infimum) has to be zero.

Comment: Could you please explain the $|1-xy| \le 1+|xy|$ part? It is obvious, but it is hard to find...

Comment: That's triangle inequality @HerpDerpington